# Maven multimodule projects linking in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have a maven multi module project which has 5 modules. Some of my modules depend on one or more other modules, I am successfully able build the project and in eclipse also I am not getting any errors. However there is one problem which is bothering me, when i ctrl + click in my code and the class is defined on some other project eclipse does not open the file in the editor. I know i can attach the source code using maven but still i wont be able to make changes to that file.
Is there any way to be able to link projects in eclipse through maven?

Comment: could anyone please suggest something.

Comment: Are all projects in the same workspace?

Comment: All projects belong to same git repo(child projects at the same level as the pom of parent) and imported into same eclipse workspace/

Comment: Click on the identifier and press F3 instead of Ctrl+Click and look into the status bar. Do you see a red error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to be able to link projects in eclipse through maven?

That behaviour is the default. To check if for some reason that default is not in effect for your project, right click your project (the project you want to jump **from**) and go to "Maven". If there is an option "Disable Workspace Resolution" the workspace resolution is switched **on**, meaning you can theoretically jump from that project.

If you still cannot jump, then the project you want to jump **to** is not in your workspace. Take into account that for eclipse to identfy one project as dependency of another, everything including version must match.

Also check what rest_day said. You must have the projects importet as maven projects, but running eclipse:eclipse is not required anymore with current (up to ca 2 year old) eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the projects as Maven projects?

Also, could you go to the root of the project and run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

> eclipse:eclipse
>
> Full name:
>
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.10:eclipse
>
> Description:
>
> Generates the following eclipse configuration files:
>
> > .project and .classpath files 
> >     .setting/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs with project specific compiler settings various configuration files for WTP (Web Tools Project), if the parameter wtpversion is set to a valid version (WTP configuration is not generated by default)
>
> If this goal is run on
>   a multiproject root, dependencies between modules will be configured
>   as direct project dependencies in Eclipse (unless useProjectReferences
>   is set to false).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd>, click on the identifier and press <kbd>F3</kbd>. If you now see a red text reading "Current text selection cannot be opened in an editor", you've been hit by [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430605).

See this question for a solution: [How do I get rid of "Current text selection cannot be opened in an editor" in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18227733/how-do-i-get-rid-of-current-text-selection-cannot-be-opened-in-an-editor-in-ec)