# Javascript Open Declaration (Ctrl+Click) broken after upgrading to Eclipse Mars

Tags: javascript, eclipse-mars

After upgrading from Eclipse Luna to Mars, I found that the Ctrl+Click/F3 drill-down functionality (Open Declaration) does not work anymore, throwing an error:

> Problems opening an editor. See error log for more details.

The following entries appear in the eclipse Error Log itself:

> Unexpected runtime error while computing a text hover (with a NullPointerException)
>   error during type inferencing (with a NullPointerException)
>   Internal Error (with InvocationTargetException caused by NullPointerException)

Some additional observations:

- The problem occurs on a JavaScript-configured project which had no problems in Luna
- The problem **does not** occur on another JavaScript project, whose JS files are much less complicated (70KB in 5 files vs. 5MB in 19 files (excluding ExtJS libraries) in the problematic project)
- I installed Mars on top of Luna using the recommended update process (https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse%3F)

  - To ensure it is not due to something wrong during the upgrade, I also downloaded Eclipse Mars for Java EE Developers and installed it fresh.
  - I did the same for the project, setting it up from scratch, to exclude the possibility some old Luna setting messing up with Mars
- Open Declaration, Open Implementation, etc. work in Java, only Javascript seems to be affected

Does anybody have an idea if there is something I can do to fix this problem or it is an issue with Eclipse? (I couldn't find anything related in Eclipse's Bugzilla)

Comment: On my machine it is working perfectly. I have installed fresh copy of Eclipse Mars . Did you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/a/11772843/3628106.

Comment: I had tried all of the points in the suggested log, except from running Eclipse with -clean. It did not help either, now that I ran it.
I've updated the description - another project, with simpler/smaller JS files, does not have the problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an [issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=473368) in Eclipse Bugzilla.
It had already been fixed internally and the fix is included in Mars SR1.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem with Spring Tool Suite (Version: 3.8.3.RELEASE), Eclipse Neon.2 (4.6.2). After I was installed [Tern Eclipse IDE](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/tern-eclipse-ide)  plugin , this problem was gone.

Below is how I configure this plugin for someone who got the problem as me

1. right-click on the project *(at project Explorer)* > Configure > Convert to Tern Project..
2. choose modules as you want *(for me : I only choosed **jquery**)*
3. right-click on the project *(at project Explorer)* > Properties > General > Editors > Text Editors > Hyperlinking and disable as below screenshoots for better performance in HTML/JSP files.

**1. Disable built-in JavaScript Hyperlinking** 
*(this will help you to direct to go it's declaration with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+**click**)*

[image]

**2. Allow only in JS Editor for Tern plugin**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't helped me. Eclipse 2019‑03.