# Kotlin databinding CTRL+click doesn't jump to XML

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I used data binding with Java for Android projects, now I'm migrating to kotlin and I found a wired issue when I try to access XML views from Activities or Fragments.

When I press CTRL + click on a view it jumps to `MyActivityBinding.java` but it should jump to `activity_main.xml` is there a way to change it?

Comment: Try to follow this link once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769513/ctrlclick-doesnt-work-in-eclipse-juno

Comment: I'm using Andorid Studio not Eclipse

Comment: @Choletski have you find solution?